# SQLite compound WHERE logic

Tags: date, sqlite

First question here! recently started using SQLite; not much prior programming experience.

I am working on a tool to generate reports in Excel from a sqlite database.

The report I am currently working on depends on finding the average revenue per month for products released in a certain timeframe.

For example, the datum for September 2011 would be the average of all the revenue accrued in that month for all products released in September, August and July.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT date,avg(total_revenue) from product_table join revenue_table

WHERE(

(
sales_month=strftime('%m',release_date,'+1 months') AND
sales_year=strftime('%Y',release_date,'+1 months')
)

OR

(
sales_month=strftime('%m',release_date,'+2 months') AND
sales_year=strftime('%Y',release_date,'+2 months')
)

OR

(
sales_month=strftime('%m',release_date,'+3 months') AND
sales_year=strftime('%Y',release_date,'+3 months')
)

OR

(
sales_month=strftime('%m',release_date) AND
sales_year=strftime('%Y',release_date)
)

AND
additional_filters=true
)

group by sales_year, sales_month;
```

I think that this produces the data that I want, but even if it does, it is hideous, unwieldy and inextensible.

My first question is whether this sort of nested logic works within sqlite WHERE statements
i.e. can you construct a query like:

```
where ((a=b AND c=d) OR (a=d AND b=c))
```

I have experimented with changing one of the OR's to a where, but I can't make sense of the results.

My other question is whether there is a more elegant way of doing this, as ideally the user will be able to control the timeframe (i.e. change from three months to one month).

Note that invoices are collated monthly, but products are released throughout the month.
I have tried constructing a date string from the sales_month,sales_year and having a query including something like this:

```
where (julianday(sales_date)-julianday(release_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 90 AND addtional_filters)
```

but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression in the `WHERE` clause can be arbitrarily complex.

Your sale/release comparison could be done with the following expression:

```
WHERE date(sales_date, 'start of month')
      BETWEEN date(release_date, 'start of month')
          AND date(release_date, 'start of month', '+2 months')
  AND ...
```